# Cassandra cluster scaling down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I have a 3-node cassandra cluster in aws cloud which is running perfectly.
The traffic is low and I want to scale it down to two or single node due to economic constraints.

What could be the right practice here? Can I pause the other 2 nodes?
Is some data loss is expected?

Answer (score 0):

If the cassandra nodes are available and you decommission them "gracefully", no data loss occurs. The reason is because when you decommission nodes token/data re-distribution occurs (so the process takes some time). If you "hard force" a node out (or if it becomes unavailable for any reason) and your RF is not configured to have data redundancy (e.g. set to 1), you will lose data. So try to remove the node "gracefully" (nodetool decommission (not sure how that's done in AWS)) and when you're done, be sure your RF settings per keyspace are correct (i.e. don't have RF > nodes and be sure it's > 1 if you want redundancy).

-Jim